# Python3: Extracting a function from a list and have it operate on an argument

Tags: python, list, function

In Python3 how can I extract a function from a list and have it called on an argument?
Meaning, what is the correct way to implement the following (***not*** working) code:

```
arr = [int()]
arr[0]("3") # would like to mean: int("3") resulting in the outcome 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the `parens`

```
 arr = [int]

arr[0]("3")


In [5]: arr = [int]

In [6]: arr[0]("3")
Out[6]: 3

In [7]: type(arr[0]("3"))
Out[7]: builtins.int
In [8]: arr[0]("3") * 10
Out[8]: 30
```

Comment: Wow, that easy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, that easy ;), `arr[0]("3")` is the same as `int("3")`

Comment: Remember that old saying that "everything in python is an object". Try not to think of `func()` as the identifier for a function. Rather, its identifier is `func`, and the parens are acting on the object referred to by `func`. So when you said `int()`, the parens were calling it right there, and putting the value into the array, rather than the function object.